# Change <textarea> font size when the value's length reaches a certain number

Tags: javascript, html

As stated in the title, I want to change the textarea's font size after 50 or more values have been entered. For instance, my textarea's normal font size is 20px, but when I input something greater than or equal to 50 characters, the font size changes to 14px.

I tried doing

```js
let textArea = document.getElementById("post");
var maxNumOfChars = 50;
const countCharacters = () => {
    let numOfEnteredChars = textArea.value.length;
};
textArea.addEventListener("inputs", countCharacters);
if(numOfEnteredChars >= 50) {
    textArea.style.fontSize = "1px";
}
```

```html
<textarea name="post" placeholder="What's on you mind?" id="post"></textarea>
```

For sure, there's something wrong in my code (I'm a javascript beginner) so please correct my code or make a better way for doing it. Thanks

Comment: btw, it's supposed to be
`if(numOfEnteredChars >= maxNumOfChars)`

Comment: (Offtopic) Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do that? What are you building? From a UI perspective the font size switch looks more like an application bug. From a UX and accessibility perspective is non inclusive. You should rather use `em` or `rem`.

Comment: Well, the ui looks weird having a large font-size so making it smaller after a few characters makes it better and more comfortable to eyes (my friends also said that it's better like that) .

Plus, I don't really know how to use em/rem, since it's pretty confusing for me so I'm relying on px/vw/% more

Comment: Well, then quickly go learn `em` and `rem` because you're going to use them 90% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - event must be `input`, instead of `inputs`

The other thing - is the corrected business logic

```js
const textArea = document.getElementById('post');

const resizeTextArea = () => {
    textArea.style.fontSize = textArea.value.length <= 50 ? '20px' : '14px';
};

textArea.addEventListener('input', resizeTextArea);
```

```html
<textarea id="post"></textarea>
```

Comment: This perfectly worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your `countCharacters` is a void function that doesn't return anything. And `numOfEnteredChars` variable inside the function is only accessible within that **function's scope**. You can't access to it outside the function.

```
let textArea = document.getElementById("post");

textArea.addEventListener('input', () => {
    textArea.value.length < 50 ? textArea.style.fontSize = '50px' : textArea.style.fontSize = '14px'
})
```

Worked for me!